# Insert multiple inputs with same name, into one array [row] (separated by "^")

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple inputs (never being the same, because it's a dynamic add/remove jquery script, and it is all dependent on how many "tracks" the user wants to enter). I WILL NEVER KNOW HOW MANY WILL BE THERE. Below is an example of if a user chooses to add four "tracks" to their "mixtape".

```
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="textbox" id="track[1]" name="track[]" >
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="textbox" id="track[2]" name="track[]" >
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="textbox" id="track[3]" name="track[]" >
<input size="32" class="mixtapetrack" type="textbox" id="track[4]" name="track[]" >
```

When the form is submited (PHP POSTED), I want to take all of the inputs and combine them into one array, but sepparating them all by **"^^^"**.

---

This is what I have so far, for rendering out the inputs (NOT WORKING).

```
$trackVAR = $_POST['track'];

         $allmixtapetracks = "";

         foreach ($trackVAR as $value) {

    $allmixtapetracks .= '' . $value . '^';
  }
```

And This is what i'm using to insert into my table (WORKS, tested it without the variable and entered absoloute data)

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mixtapes (title, songs, posted_by_id, description, date) 
     VALUES('$mixtapetitle','$allmixtapetracks','$posted_by_id','$mixtapedescription', now())")  
     or die (mysql_error());
```

---

In the end I want it to look like this inside of the songs row

> Title of first song haha **^^^** Title of second song!!! **^^^** The
>   Title Of the third! **^^^** And The Title OF the Fourth

Comment: Please make sure you are escaping your inputs. NEVER allow data from outside the PHP script (e.g. $_POST data) into a db query unescaped. Also the mysql_ family of functions are deprecated. You should use at least mysqli_ if not PDO (PDO provides an easy way for you to escape data too).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode)

```
echo implode($trackVAR, " ^^^ ");
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Where would I place this?

Comment: thank you very much for taking your time to help me. and yes, i am just a beginner. I have much to learn. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your following code:

```
$trackVAR = $_POST['track'];

$allmixtapetracks = "";

foreach ($trackVAR as $value) {
    $allmixtapetracks .= '' . $value . '^';
}
```

with this:

```
$allmixtapetracks=implode('^^^',$_POST['track']);
```

Comment: I don't understand where this is to go?

Comment: thank you very much for taking your time in helping me. However, it's still only displaying the first input's value.